# Parsing simple types in FParsec

Tags: f#, fparsec

I'm trying to parse standard simple types (in the sense of lambda calculus) using FParsec, but I've having difficulty going from a Lex/Yacc style to that used in FParsec, specifically with respect to recursive definitions.

Examples of the types I am trying to parse are:

- o
- o -> o
- (o -> o -> o) -> o

And here is my attempt:

```
    type SType =
      | Atom
      | Arrow of SType * SType

    let ws = spaces
    let stype, styperef = createParserForwardedToRef()

    let atom = pchar 'o' .>> ws |>> (fun _ -> Atom)

    let arrow = pipe2 (stype .>> (pstring "->" .>> ws)) 
                      stype
                      (fun t1 t2 -> Arrow (t1,t2))

    let arr = parse {
                let! t1 = stype
                do!  ws
                let! _  = pstring "->"
                let! t2 = stype
                do!  ws
                return Arrow (t1,t2)
              }

    styperef := choice [ pchar '(' >>. stype .>> pchar ')';
                         arr;
                         atom ]

    let _ = run stype "o -> o"`
```

When I load this into the interactive the last line causes a stack overflow (ironically quite hard to search for these days). I can imagine why, given that there are recursive references, but I would have thought the one token lookahead would have prevented following the first (bracketed) choice in `stype`. I assume therefore that it must be choosing `arr`, which chooses `stype`, and so on. But how to prevent this loop?

I'm interested in comments on idiomatic use of the library as well as corrections to my attempted solution.

Comment: This could be want you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186230/recursive-grammars-in-fparsec

Comment: Thanks, I have read that question/reply, but I can't quite see how to carry over the answer to my problem. I will have another look though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you work with FParsec you need to parse sequences with the help of the [sequence combinators](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/parser-overview.html#parsing-sequences) instead of left-recursion. In your case you could for example use the `sepBy1` combinator:

```
open FParsec

type SType =
     | Atom
     | Arrow of SType * SType

let ws = spaces : Parser<unit, unit>
let str_ws s = pstring s >>. ws

let stype, stypeRef = createParserForwardedToRef()

let atom = str_ws "o" >>% Atom

let elem = atom <|> between (str_ws "(") (str_ws ")") stype

do stypeRef:= sepBy1 elem (str_ws "->") 
              |>> List.reduceBack (fun t1 t2 -> Arrow(t1, t2))

let _ = run stype "o -> o"
```

Comment: I keep forgetting sepBy.  Nice answer!

Comment: This is great thanks, like the use of >>% as well. However, this doesn't capture the right-associativity of "->". I changed the definition of stypeRef to `chainr1 elem ((str_ws "->") >>% (fun t1 t2 -> Arrow (t1,t2)))`, although presumably you could use a right-associative version of `List.reduce` as well.

Comment: I've replaced `reduce` with `reduceBack` to parse the arrow as a right-associative operator. I find the straightforward solution using `sepBy` and `reduceBack` cleaner than the `chainr` implementation, especially because the reduction function is a constant. Since the arrow is a right-associative operator, you always have to build some kind of intermediate stack or list with the elements of the sequence, so using `chainr1` here also has no efficiency advantage. On the contrary, it should be a bit slower, as it also needs to keep record of the parsed reduction functions.

Answer (score 0):

This runs, but is probably hacked together too much.  The `type Parser...` stuff is from the FParsec docs to avoid compiler errors.

```
type SType = 
    | Atom 
    | Arrow of SType * SType

type UserState = unit
type Parser<'t> = Parser<'t, UserState>


let ws = spaces

let atom : Parser<_> = pchar 'o' .>> ws |>> (fun _ -> Atom)

let rec term =
    parse {
        // Force something to come before another term.  Either
        // an atom, or a term in parens.
        let! first = choice [atom;
                             (pstring "(" .>> ws) >>. term .>> 
                              (pstring ")" .>> ws)]

        // Check if this is an arrow.  If not, just return first.
        let! res = choice [((pstring "->") .>> ws) >>. term |>> (fun x ->
                               Arrow (first, x));
                           preturn first]
        return res
        }
```